# MySQL SELECT DISTINCT how to join some corresponding columns to query result

Tags: mysql, select, distinct

I have a table with

```
id,column1, column2, column3,column4,column5
```

MySQL SELECT DISTINCT returns me exactly what I need and **this query must remains exactly AS IS**

```
SELECT DISTINCT column1,column3 from tablename
```

But as an output I have only 2 columns as requested in DISTINCT query above

```
column1,column3
```

**Question - how to join to this result other corresponding columns from the same table ?**

For example

```
column1,column3,id,column5
```

Spent a couple of hours in Google, the two 'nearest' idea is something like

```
SELECT DISTINCT column1,column3 
from tablename AS tbl1 
INNER JOIN (SELECT id,column5 from tablename) AS tbl2
```

But such a query anyway returns me ONLY

```
column1,column3
```

My Expected result should be
`column1,column3 (exactly as a result of SELECT DISTINCT) + two other columns id,column3` - so that I could save this result to a new table with 4 columns.
But I have only two columns as I told above.

EXAMPLE added 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1e4472/1

Please, pay attention - the query result does not show ID 4 because this ID has duplicates in BOTH fields - company and city. So this is exactly what I need.

So, HOW to show in results not only COMPANY and CITY, but also, for example, ID and MANAGER ?

Comment: some sample data and expected results would make your question more clear.

Comment: If you want to put an extra column in your resultset (i.e. column 5), then you must select that column in your query. And that can't be done without modifying your existing query.

Comment: if there is more than one id that matches a row, which id should it pick? I think you need do use count min or max with a group by?

Comment: specifically concat() won't work here because it intends to do the exact opposite task of what you want to do. Concat is used to mege multiple column into one while you want to add another column.

Comment: Why I say expected result and data sample - I mean examples for the data you actually have(the values) , and how you want it to look at the end. Not in words! but in tables format .

Comment: @Harshil you're right, concat is stupid idea, I've removed the one

Comment: Gentlemen, you all are right, let me prepare an example at sqlfiddle, will return in about 30 min.

Comment: If you share your table schema with sample data then your issue will be easy to understand solve. It'll save a lot of time for everyone here.

Comment: @Serge Yeah! Fiddle is good idea. create fiddle and notify here.

Comment: @Harshil added example http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1e4472/1

Comment: @Serge so for London which manager do you want, Smith or Smith2? How do you know that it's skipping ID 4? Maybe it's skipping ID 1? Do you want it to always use  the first when there are duplicates?

Comment: @isaace I want only that manager who relates to SELECT DISTINCT result - so that Smith2 should NOT be there

Comment: Look at @Harshil 's answer. The distinct doesn't use any specific one. You need do use min or max on the ID.

Comment: @isaace is right. You should define a particular approach. Whenever duplication happens, if you want the original or first record with those values, then my answer will work. But if you want latest duplicated record, then 2nd query in sagi's answer will do the job.Conclusion is, you should know what you want and why you want that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of duplication, if you want to display the first(original) record with the same values of company & city (i.e. like here you want to show id=1 not id=4) then following query should work:

```
SELECT min(id) as id,manager,company,city 
FROM DistinctResult
group by company,city;
```

[Click here for Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1e4472/14/0)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Perfect solution ! Yes, I went to wrong direction trying JOIN and CONCAT.

Answer (score 0):

Simply :

```
SELECT DISTINCT Column1,Column3,id,column5
```

Or alternatively , if there is more than 1 value for these columns:

```
 SELECT Column1,Column3,MAX(id),MAX(column5)
 GROUP BY Column1,Column3
```

But it really depends on the requirement and you weren't very clear.

Comment: I've edited my question, SELECT DISTINCT must remains the same as it returns EXACTLY what I need. It would be very simple if I could use `SELECT DISTINCT Column1,Column3,id,column5`- but not, it does not solve

Comment: It's even less clear after your edit! Why does it has to be that way?! Why not just post data sample, and expected result so I can understand better?! Why not use alternative?! Or in short - What do you want to do ????? @Serge